# Favicon change for custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, favicons

I am trying to change favicon for custom module in same theme but stuck in it. Actually I want to show different favicon when specific module action in called wanted to show different favicon and for all remaining modules and theme remains the same as old one.

Can anyone give me any idea how can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean that if any specific page is called then you want to show different favicon?

Comment: Yes, but did this thanks for your reply

Comment: Ok so you have done this already?

Comment: yes I use the model class in my controller